# Отключение проверки статуса сертификата c#

Tags: c#

При подписывании файлов сертификатами криптопровайдер лезет в сеть для проверки статуса сертификата (обнаружились открытые сокеты к серверам, указанным в сертификатах).

UPD адреса указаны в самих сертификатах в полях "Доступ к сведениям центра сертификации" и "Точка распределения списка отзыва (CRL)". Провайдер - КРИПТОПРО

В рамках текущей задачи необходимости в этом нет (подписывающий компьютер отключен от глобальной сети и такая операция кроме задержки ничего не предоставляет).

Можно ли средствами .net при подписывании указать, что не нужно никуда лезть, "просто подпиши"?

UPD кусок кода подписи

```
        X509Certificate2 signerCert = _cert; // _cert - статичная переменная
        // Создаем объект ContentInfo по сообщению.
        // Это необходимо для создания объекта SignedCms.
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(data);
        SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);

        // Определяем подписывающего, объектом CmsSigner.
        CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(signerCert);

        // Подписываем CMS/PKCS #7 сообщение.
        // судя по всему вот здесь  и создаются подключения к серверам
        cms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, false);

        var dataSignedHash = cms.Encode();
```

Comment: Какой имеено "криптодрайвер" вы используете. Покажите кусок кода. Я подписывал через сертефикат - у меня не лезит в интернет.

Comment: @nick_n_a добавил

Comment: Я не имел дело с CMS, у меня используется Х509+RSA, но... попробуйте это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687798/cms-signing-in-net-with-certificate-chain-not-in-local-trusted-certificate-stor

Comment: @nick_n_a не совсем то, что я ожидал - с подписанием проблем нет, нужно чтобы он не пытался проверять сертификаты на валидность. А там предлагается просто исключить дерево сертифиатов